# How can I add a picture into a placeholder using PowerPoint 2003 VBA?

Tags: matlab, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create PowerPoint slides using MATLAB. It seems like it is basically the same as using VBA to create PowerPoint slides, except with slightly different syntax. The function and variable names are all the same.

Anyway....I can add a picture to a slide. I can also add a specific layout, which creates some placeholders. But I can't figure out how to add a picture and link it to a specific placeholder. I want to import 4 pictures into PowerPoint and apply the "4 Object" layout. I could obviously manually place the pictures in the same locations that the layout would choose. But I would like to link them to the placeholders in case I ever need to change the layout.

Does anyone know how to add a picture and link it to a placeholder?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

There are a few MATLAB code submissions on the MathWorks File Exchange that may help you move figures from MATLAB into PowerPoint with specific layouts:

- [saveppt2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19322) by Jedediah Frey.
- [subplotPPT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20949) by Mark Hoyle.
- [saveppt](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/340) by Mark Brown.

The last submission has inspired the first 2, along with a few others that may also be of help to you (links are provided in the Acknowledgements section of the last submission).

Hope this helps!